# What is the difference between callback, high-order functions, and callback queue

Tags: javascript, callback, functional-programming

At this point, I have a question on what exactly is a **callback**, what makes it different from a **high-order function** and how does it relate to the concept of **callback queue**?

From MDN: [Callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)

> A callback function is a function passed into another function as an argument, which is then invoked inside the outer function to complete some kind of routine or action.

Looks like there's an overlap with the definition of High-Order Functions. A function that gets passed (and later invoked) to another function.

This is the MDN example of a callback:

```
function greeting(name) {
  alert('Hello ' + name);
}

function processUserInput(callback) {
  var name = prompt('Please enter your name.');
  callback(name);
}

processUserInput(greeting);
```

No doubt so far.

I then faced with the idea of **Event Loop** and **Callback queue**.

```
 console.log("me first");

  setTimeout(function asyncLog() {
       console.log("i am the last")
  }, 2000);

  console.log("me second")
```

Turns out the `seTimeout` function, is actually a JavaScript wrapper that interfaces under the hood with Web Browser API (timer). setTimeout passes to the Timer API a function (asyncLog) and the timer (2000ms).

When the timer feature (in the web browser) has completed its work, will send the function `asyncLog` in the `callback queue` ready to be invoked in the call stack as soon as the JS call stack is (1) Empty and (2) has processed everything in the global execution context.

So after the last line `console.log("me second")` is processed the Event Loop passes the callback function `asyncLog` from the callback queue to the call stack, and executes it.

The final order is:

```
me first
me second
i am the last
```

In the first example, even though we are referring to `greeting` as the "callback" function, my understanding suggests that the entire mechanism of Callback queue gets skipped entirely: we're not doing anything asynchronous and we're not interfacing with the web browser API (everything is self-contained into JS).

If so, why do we refer to functions that get passed into other functions as callbacks (and not as simple High-order functions), when they have nothing to do with the callback queue and with the asynchronous world?

Comment: A high-order function (HOF) is a function that returns a function, as opposed to a simple value. A callback is a function that gets "called back" by something else once a (usually asynchronous) process is complete; a callback could return a value, or a function, or nothing. Therefore a callback may or may not also be a HOF, depending on the API of whatever's calling it back. It's not clear to me where you see a conflict.

Comment: @JonasW. I'm referring to the greeting function.

Comment: Yes, the first example is not asynchronous and the callback is invoked immediately. A callback may or may not end up getting placed in the callback queue, depending on what invokes it. I'm still not sure how that leads to your conclusion *"If so..."*.

Comment: Nevermind, seems i have to read more carefully.

Comment: @jonrsharpe makes sense Jonathan. Does a function happen to end up in the callback queue only when it's "pushed" there by a web browser API? (Like in the setTimeout example).

Comment: @leonardofed one could say so, yes.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Adding_messages

Comment: thanks @jonrsharpe. Are these all the web browser APIs that can push cb functions to the callback queue?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API

Comment: Hi Leonardofed hope you figured out this already. I asked a similar question and also confused, I guess only call back functions that signal event(like web api) will be pushed to such queue:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53919515/javascript-callback-function-not-executing-as-intended

Comment: @mzoz yes I read your question. don't conflate the two. cb are baby functions that get passed in HOF and called at a later point. they are not necessary asynchronous.

Comment: I've also found a particularly good article (https://bytearcher.com/articles/does-taking-a-callback-make-a-function-asynchronous/) especially the last part where the author gave examples of async callback situations which I think MDN doc should explicitly explain but failed to do so.

Comment: YES. I have been struggling with a similar concept if anyone can help. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59728065/how-can-you-use-a-callback-to-guarantee-sequential-execution)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) is a function that takes another function(s) as an argument(s) **and/or** returns a function to its callers.

A [callback function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) is a function that is passed to another function with the expectation that the other function will call it.

So a callback is not necessarily itself a higher-order function, but a function which receives a callback as an argument *is*. Consider a very common case, the DOM event listener:

```
elem.addEventListener('click', console.log);
```

Here, `.addEventListener` is a higher-order function that takes another function (`console.log`) which it then calls. Although `console.log` is a callback here, it is not in this case acting as a higher-order function itself.

The event loop is a mechanism exposed to you by the underlying runtime. Here we are going to imagine that we have to do this manually, using an array as a queue:

```
const queue = [];
const setTimeout = (f, ...args) => {
  queue.push([f, args]);
};

const runQueuedCallbacks = () => {
  let queued;
  while (queued = queue.shift()) {
    let [f, args] = queued;
    f(...args);
  }
};

setTimeout(console.log, 'first');   // queues a call to log
setTimeout(console.log, 'second');  // queues a call to log
console.log('zero-th');             // directly calls log, prints first

// at this point there's no more code to execute, so runQueuedCallbacks runs
// and sequentially steps through the enqueued callbacks.
```

In real life it's a little more complicated than this because of things like microtask resolution (also what happens when a queued callback queues another callback) but that should hopefully give you a decent picture.

Answer (score 0):

A higher-order function is a function that takes another function(s) as an argument(s) and/or returns a function to its callers. Here, the function(s) which is passed as the argument is called as the call-back function.
However, the callback function may be a higher order function too, or it may be not. Lets see examples.

```
function printString(callbackHof, callback_only, str) {
   str +=' concated first';
  callbackHof( callback_only,str);
}

function concatFirst(callback_only, str)
{
  callback_only(str);
}

function concatAgain(str)
{
  str += ' contated again';
  console.log(str);
}

printString(concatFirst, concatAgain, 'anything');
```

The output is ='anything concated first contated again' for clarification.

Here printString() is a higher order function which takes two functions and a string as arguments. The function arguments of printString() are concatFirst() and concatAgain(), these concatFirst() and concatAgain() fumctions are callback functions by definition.

Here, concatFirst() is both callback and higher order function as it is passed as printString()'s argument, then also takes concatAgain() callback function as it's own input.

And, concatAgain() is just a callback function, because it is called with just a string argument & no further function argument.

Finally, callback queue is the mechanism that browsers or javascript compilers follow to perform asynchronous & callback operations perfectly with the help of event-loop.