# How can you use a callback to guarantee sequential execution?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, asynccallback

I am trying to wrap my head around callbacks and I do not understand how callbacks **guarantee** that a statement will execute **after(in terms of time)** another statement which takes an **unknown** amount of time. I do not care about  **promises,await,async, etc** but just plain callbacks as I am trying to learn.

---

For example below, my method will execute the callback before the unknown time event has occured. I can see how callbacks can be used to execute something **because** an event occurred but **not** how they can be used to **guarantee** that something will be executed **after(in terms of time)** something else has finished executing and returned something meaningful.

```js
function foo(callback) {
    setTimeout(() => console.log("Do something with unknown time"),
        2000);
    callback();
}

function callback() {
    console.log("Execute callback");
}

foo(callback);
```

---

So what I am asking is can callbacks be used to guarantee execution sequence in the time domain ? Or is their only purpose responding to events ?

Comment: The callback here is not the function called `callback()`, but the inline call to `console.log()`.

Comment: Yes you have a point in the sense that it is the callback method for the setTimeout method. But what I want to know is how my callback can be made to run after the first statement in the foo method. What i want the code to do is wait for 2 seconds, execute the callback of the setTimeout i.e the console log and then execute the callback to my foo method

Comment: Your function isn't really a callback, though. Anyway, here's a similar [example of using `async` and `await` to do this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: What would I need to make it into a true callback. Like the one i provide to the setTimeout method. I want a situation where my method is a kind of like setTimeout but instead of waiting for a specific time, it waits for the complete execution of the previous statement.

Answer (score 1):

You have asked two questions,

1. Is callback execution sequence guaranteed?
2. Is callback only respond to events ?

#### Answer

1. Yes.

From my understanding, `callback` is just calling another function to be run now (when it is called)

> It is guarantee to run immediately when you call it.

To ensure something is called before the callback is triggered, simply put the things you want to call execute first before callback is conducted.

e.g. from your code, by modify it a bit, callback is guarantee to run after the console.log is executed.

```js
function foo(callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Do something with unknown time");
        callback();
    }, 2000);
}

function callback() {
    console.log("Execute callback");
}

foo(callback);
```

It is the `setTimeout` which defers the execution, and is not related to callback methodology.

2. Sure, callback can be used as a callback to respond to event, just like `elem.addEventListener("click", callback);`. But not only that.

A simple example will be illustrated below.

e.g.

```js
var map = function(arr, callback) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    result.push(callback(arr[i]));
  }
  return result;
};

map([0, 1, 2, 3], function(item) {
  return item * 2;
})
```

### Edited

This edit is referring to

> For example, if I am making a database call, I do not know how much time it is going to take for the data to be retrieved. If i try to access it before it has arrived, I'll get an error.

Calling a database, is by no means different from an async http request. So here, I will use XMLHttpRequest to demonstrate how to use callback to ensure this. But normally, these are features provided in browser or node.js already. So you do not need to write it by your own. Of course, to prevent callback hell, I will personally prefer use of `Promise` or `async/await`. But this is a bit out of topic.

So let see how XMLHttpRequest can use callback to handle async task.

```
var sendRequest = function(callback) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       callback(this); 
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "filename", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

and you can use callback to handle async event. Sometime you dont know when it will happen. And the basic idea how it works is from the example I have said in answer 1.

Comment: I understand that putting the callback(); inside the body of the setTimeout will make it execute after the console.log() method but that's not my main problem because I am just using the setTmeout method to mock a method which will take an unknown amount of time.

Comment: just edit the answer with an example, please have a look, and see if solved your problem

Comment: No it does not solve my problem. when i ask about execution sequence, I mean completion of execution. For example, if I am making a database call, I do not know how much time it is going to take for the data to be retrieved. If i try to access it before it has arrived, I'll get an error. In such a scenario, is there any way to work with callbacks ?

Answer (score 1):

Callbacks is a way of invoking a function that is passed as a parameter to invoker function(in your example `foo`). Callbacks guarantee that a function will be invoked if no error occurs before it's call inside the function. Callbacks aren't asynchronous either but the way it executes later inside the function after some line of code makes everyone think it as asynchonous at first.

And as you've added `setTimeout` function on the above example, `setTimeout` is an asynchronous callback envoker function that calls it's callback(in your code `() => console.log("Do something with unknown time")`) asynchronously after a certain defined time(`2000`). So, `setTimeout` wont stop the execution for 2 seconds as you've expected, instead it let's the further line of codes execute without worrying about what will happen inside it's callback. So, the `callback()` will trigger at that instant when `foo(callback);` is triggered.

[You can find more info about callback in here.](https://dev.to/nileshsanyal/javascript-callback-functions-in-depth-guide-for-2019-gj7)

Comment: So callbacks have nothing to do with the TIMING of execution but just the EVENT as I was guessing. I was confused because there is a lot of material which claims that callbacks are used to handle asynchronous events. I know that setTimeout wont block execution which is why I was using it to make my point. I wonder how fetch requests were handled before promises, await, etc.

Comment: Yep, that's what it is. Even inside asynchronous function calls, everything happens will callback events, a `Promise` has it's *resolve* and *reject* callbacks which can be handled later. These callbacks helps to invoke such success or failure events when certain events occurs(such as `resolve` callback for successful execution and `reject` callback for failure ore error in execution). I hope it makes sense. You can find more info in here: 

https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/callbacks-promises-and-async-await-ad4756e01d90

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you mean correctly, you can use callback as an event to do something, such as: *onerror, oncomplete...*

In this example, we start to run `todo` function, and we have `oncomplete` function which can be used as callback to do something after completing works on `todo` function.

While running, if there is some error, it will be logged to `onerror` function.

```js
function todo(oncomplete, onerror) {
    try {
        console.log("Start...");

        console.log("Do something with unknown time");

        setTimeout(() => oncomplete(),2000);
        
        // you can try to throw error here to test
        // throw new Error("Some error message...");
    } catch (e) {
        onerror(e);
    }
}

function oncomplete() {
    console.log("Done!");
}

function onerror(e) {
    console.error(e.message);
}

todo(oncomplete, onerror);
```

Comment: This is not what I want. To see my problem consider that in this above example if console.log("Do something with unknown time") takes an unknown time (say 5 sec). Then, the setTimeout method will run before the console.log. So output will be Start--> Done --> Do something with unknown time(3 sec later)

Comment: @HarshLimaye So, that means you had already put it in the wrong *place*? What's happen if you try again following to my steps?